# Handwritten digits recognition

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, project

I am going to do a neural network project about handwritten digits recognition but this area is well-studied. I have found some essays online but most of them are before 2012. Could anyone tell me what is the state-of-the-art technology and current issue of this area ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO you can refer `MNIST DATASET` because it is made up of a huge number of corner cases and it contains `28*28 pixel` images with ***42000 rows and 786 cols*** so that you can easily get an idea
how much data you want to train and for predictions without needing the `train_test_split`.

So that you can get a proper idea of the dataset and you can Visualize it.

dataset link:- [MNIST DATASET](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data)

refer video:- [HANDWRITTEN DIGIT RECOGNITION](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hP3XFNq-xk&t=8s)

Answer (score 0):

The state of the art is almost always determined as the result of performance against a particular dataset.  For handwritten digits, the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) is the one I have seen most commonly referenced (though I'm not an expert in the area).  For any dataset you should be able to easily find the state of the art performance against it very near where you download it.